# Laravel / Lumen relationship - join other table where condition retrieve wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen, eloquent

I'm experiencing a weird problem retrieving some data from the database when comparing two dates.

Database structure:
Users, reservations, reservation_services, services_price_history

Based on the above tables:
An user has many reservations, a reservation have many services, and a service has many price histories.

I need to take all user reservations, then find the service price based on the reservation date.

The problem is that when I add the date comparation condition it's not taking it into consideration

The code:

```
$users = User::with(['reservations' => function($query) use ($department_id, $date_start, $date_end) {

    // reservation services
    $query->with(['reservation_services' => function($query) {
        $query->join('reservations', 'reservation_services.reservation_id', 'reservations.id');
        $query->join('services', 'reservation_services.service_id', 'services.id');

        // Find the service price based on reservation date
        $query->join('services_price_history', function($query) {
            $query->on('reservations.salon_id', 'services_price_history.salon_id');
            $query->on('reservation_services.service_id', 'services_price_history.service_id');

            // this shoud be the condition that gives us the correct
            // price based on the reservation date
            $query->where('services_price_history.date_start', '<', 'reservations.date');
           // then we use order and limit 1
        });

        $query->select(
            'reservation_services.reservation_id',
            'reservation_services.service_id',
            'reservation_services.quantity',
            'services_price_history.price',
            'services_price_history.date_start',
            'services.name',
            DB::raw('(services_price_history.price * reservation_services.quantity) as total')
        );
        $query->orderBy('services_price_history.id', 'desc');
    }]);
}])->get();
```

This is the output:

```
[
   {
      "id":10,
      "first_name":"Mihaela",
      "last_name":"Radulescu",
      "reservations":[
         {
            "id":112,
            "salon_id":2,
            "client_id":161,
            "user_id":10,
            "date":"2017-10-31", // the reservation date
            "start":"10:00",
            "end":"12:00",
            "state_id":5,
            "notes":null,
            "price":"350.00",
            "reservation_services":[
               {
                  "reservation_id":112,
                  "service_id":89,
                  "quantity":1,
                  "price":"400.00",
                  "date_start":"2017-11-02", // this is wrong
                  "name":"Tratament ANTI AGE",
                  "total":"400.00"
               },
               {
                  "reservation_id":112,
                  "service_id":89,
                  "quantity":1,
                  "price":"350.00",
                  "date_start":"2017-10-19", // this is ok
                  "name":"Tratament ANTI AGE",
                  "total":"350.00"
               }
            ],
            "reservation_products":[

            ]
         },
      ]
   },
],
```

I don't really know why but this line on code

`$query->where('services_price_history.date_start', '<', 'reservations.date');`

is not working as it shoud because `'2017-11-02'` is higher than `'2017-10-31'` but it shows up in results.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$query->where('services_price_history.date_start', '<', 'reservations.date');
```

use:

```
$query->whereRaw('services_price_history.date_start < reservations.date');
```

Comment: It works as a charm! Please, can you explain me why? I can't see any difference and I'm a little frustrated. Thank you so much!

Comment: When using `where` the 3rd argument in that case was value and it was automatically bound using PDO prepared statements, and when using `whereRaw` there is no prepared statements in code shown, so now it's used exactly as it's written and this is what you needed

Comment: thank you very much. It makes sense. Any ideea how I can limit the result right after `$query->whereRaw('services_price_history.date_start < reservations.date');` ? Using `$query->limit(1)` or `first()` seems that is not gonna work.